# Online database using Firebase or XAMPP

Tags: php, firebase, xampp, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

For my school's project on Android Studio I decided to make an application that lets people take photos of places they visited and let other up vote/down vote.

The problem I stumbled upon is that I need a database online. I tried working with Firebase but couldn't make it work. Currently I am asking for help from my teacher about his work with PHP and XAMPP but I would be glad if anyone could help me before he can answer.

Any up to date guides also can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase has [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) that's technically online. But if you're going to store images, it would be better for you to use [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/) itself.

The documentation itself has code snippets to get you started. Of course, the implementation of it will be entirely up to you.

Happy coding!

Comment: I actually tried to follow the guides but I couldn't succeed to use it so I tried using XAMPP , there is a link to a problem I had using it if you could also help me in that post I will be glad :D
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40223764/xampp-doesnt-connect-php-with-database